# In custom payment method how to get a submitted credit card number in magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to retrieve a credit card number and other details  in magento 2?
[image]

Comment: this details save in database?

Comment: yes last 4 number of credit card is saved in the database  but i need the all number of the card @rakesh

Comment: if you have saved in datbase last 4 digits then get only 4 digits not other

Comment: its default store last 4 number in sales_order_payment  table, its stores defaults  @rakesh

Comment: Your CC data will be got in function assignData().  This function in app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Model/Paymentgateway.php file

Comment: Then you have a any idea to save a credit card number externally

Comment: yes, but how to retrieve it @saneer ladani, can u please explain

Comment: Did you create payment method model file and file Path Like - app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Model/ModelName.php

Comment: yes i was created like you above  mentioned path @saneer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89431/discussion-between-saneer-ladani-and-divya-sekar).